# Read Json in Rust

Tags: json, rust

I am trying to read the contents of a Json file in Rust. This file contains an array of points in the plane, like `[[1, 2], [3.5, 2.7], [0, -2.1]]`.

My first attempt at an implementation is

```
extern crate serialize;
use serialize::json;
use std::io::File;

fn read_points() -> Vec<[f64, ..2]> {
  let contents = File::open(&Path::new("../points.json")).read_to_string().unwrap();
  let points: Vec<Vec<f64>> = json::decode(contents.as_slice()).unwrap();

  points.iter().map(|&v| [v[0], v[1]]).collect::<Vec<[f64, ..2]>>()
}
```

Now I have two problems with this.

First, I get a compile error

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
```

which seems to imply that my map operation is not safe. Being a complete newbie to Rust, it is not obvious to me where `&v` resides in memory. Ideally, I would like to access the underlying array backing the `Vec<f64>`, or even better, avoid to allocate the inner vectors an read directly the json to a `Vec<[f64, ..2]>`.

Second - but less important - there are those two ugly `unwrap` calls. Now, I understand that both reading a file and parsing json may fail. Is there a way to easily combine `Result` instances, such as `flatmap` in Scala or `bind` in Haskell? Even better, something like the do notation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your second question, yes, there is `and_then()` method on `Result`, but I'm afraid that it won't work here because error types are different: `read_to_string()` returns `Result<String, IoError>` while `json::decode()` returns `Result<T, DecoderError>`, and you can't just combine them - there is no generic way to describe a union of types in Rust, so you can't express a combined error type.

There are plans to ease working with errors, they are covered by [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/201) and [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/243) RFCs, so maybe this situation will improve in future.

Now the answer to the main question.

You're getting the compile error about moving out of dereference because you're using `iter()` and dereference pattern in closure argument at the same time. This method returns an iterator which yields *references* into the vector - something which satisfies `Iterator<&Vec<f64>>` bound. This means that you can't move the values out from the vector through this iterator because it is impossible to move values out of a reference.

However, `&v` pattern means that `v` *should* be moved out from a reference, that is, this closure:

```
|&v| [v[0], v[1]]  // v is Vec<f64>
```

is equivalent to this one:

```
|r| {              // r is &Vec<f64>
    let v = *r;    // v is Vec<f64>
    [v[0], v[1]]
}
```

This pattern is only useful for types which are implicitly copyable, like `int`, or for destructuring enums/tuples/etc, but `Vec<T>` is not implicitly copyable because it has a destructor and no destructuring happens here.

First, you can leave `&` out in `&v` completely (you also don't need specifying the type parameter to `collect()` because it will be inferred from function return type):

```
points.iter().map(|v| [v[0], v[1]]).collect()
```

The reason why you can do this is that index operator is translated to trait method call which automatically dereferences its target.

However, you would express the intention better if you use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()`:

```
points.into_iter().map(|v| [v[0], v[1]]).collect()
```

`into_iter()` on `Vec<T>` returns an iterator which yields `T`, not `&T` like `iter()`, so `v` here will be of type `Vec<f64>`. `into_iter()` consumes its target, but since `points` is not used after this call, this is safe to do so and it better expresses the fact that `points` are transformed to the result.

But there is even better way. JSON decoder does not support deserializing statically sized arrays like `[f64, ..2]` because it requires supporting numbers in generic parameters, and Rust does not have them yet. But you can always write your own type and implement `Decodable` for it:

```
extern crate serialize;

use serialize::{Decoder, Decodable};
use serialize::json;

#[deriving(Show)]
struct Point(f64, f64);

impl Decodable for Point {
    fn decode<D: Decoder>(d: &mut D) -> Result<Point, D::Error> {
        d.read_tuple(2, |d| {
            d.read_tuple_arg(0, |d| d.read_f64()).and_then(|e1|
                d.read_tuple_arg(1, |d| d.read_f64()).map(|e2|
                    Point(e1, e2)
                )
            )
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = "[[1, 2], [3.5, 2.7], [0, -2.1]]";
    let v: Vec<Point> = json::decode(s).unwrap();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

(try it [here](http://is.gd/rCRh9e))

Now if you need `[f64, ..2]` you can always add a method to `Point` struct which will construct it for you.

Unfortunately, [`Decodable`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/trait.Decodable.html) and [`Decoder`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/serialize/trait.Decoder.html) are really underdocumented now so you have to rely on common sense and inspect `rustc --pretty=expanded` output when you try to implement them.

**Edit** updated with the latest Rust version

Comment: The Decoder/Decodable implementation has change a bit since October. Yurume on IRC provided me with this http://is.gd/rCRh9e which is updated to run on the Alpha release.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev thanks for taking the time to do that. With Rust being a moving target it's really helpful to have updated answers for things like this!